# Mysql order number / character combined

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a SQL table with in a product-name field with the following values:

```
10b
 9b
 8b
 7b
 6b
 5b
 4b
 3b
 2b
 1b
```

These needs to be ordered from 1 to 10, but for some reason when i select with the following order: `ORDER BY title ASC`, then i get:

```
10b
1b
2b
3b
4b
```

etc..

But that 10 needs to be after the 9, not before the 1, how is this possible?

Thank you,
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
          CAST(title AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS ORDER_FIELD
          ,title
    ORDER BY
          ORDER_FIELD ASC
```

Comment: Thank You :), i'd find another solution in the meantime as well:

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY LENGTH(title), title